# PDF could not be generated on production using wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I am trying to generate pdf and render it in production server.In local host everything works fine for me. No error while I am generating PDF. But in production getting this error.

`RuntimeError (Failed to execute: ["/home/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.6/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "--page-size", "A4", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20240308-1479705-1jl9481.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20240308-1479705-112vd26.pdf"] Error: PDF could not be generated!  Command Error: pid 1483292 exit 1 /home/app/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:86:in'block in materialize': Could not find rake-13.0.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`

In Gemfile I have used

```
 gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'

 gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 2.8'
 gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.12.6.6'
```

In Controller

```
 respond_to do |format|
        format.pdf do
          render pdf: 'certificate',
                 template: 'payments/ripicle_receipt.html.haml',
                 layout: 'payments/accounting_pdf.html.haml',
                 delete_temporary_files: true,
                 page_size: 'A4'
```

config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb file. I don't have setting in this file

On server:
ruby 2.7.6p219, Bundler version 2.1.4, ubuntu 22.4

I use `Rails c`, I tried generate pdf file. It's ok. But I request on browser, it has error

**Update**

I use `rails s' to starting server. It work. But i start server by nginx-passenger, it has this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wicked\_pdf Error: PDF could not be generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626594/wicked-pdf-error-pdf-could-not-be-generated)

Comment: `Could not find rake-13.0.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)` seems to be the crux of the error.

Comment: @Nikhilbhatt
No, it's not

Comment: yes it is. `/home/carecle/carecle-web/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.6/bin/wkhtmltopdf` is a ruby script wrapper that probably runs in an environment where it does not know about your rbenv setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current maintainer of both WickedPDF and wkhtmltopdf-binary-gem here.

`/home/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.6/bin/wkhtmltopdf` is [this](https://github.com/zakird/wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem/blob/master/bin/wkhtmltopdf) Ruby script. It is invoking the top line `!/usr/bin/env ruby` to figure out which exact binary that is part of `wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem` to execute on your production platform.

So, when your Rails app shells out to invoke `wkhtmltopdf`, the user it runs as often does not have the same Ruby environment as the application (your app runs in Bundler-managed environment, but a shell-script does not without extra setup, like installing and configuring `rbenv` for that linux user, and configuring it to run in non-interactive shells.

One way to fix this is to make sure your server also has `wkhtmltopdf_binary` installed as a system gem, but it might be difficult to get the version installed on the system to be in sync with the one in your `Gemfile.lock`.

What I would suggest you do is either code in the path to the actual binary that is needed (not the Ruby binstub), or unpack & copy the correct binary into your application's `bin/` directory, and change your WickedPDF config like so:

**config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb**

```rb
WickedPdf.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.production?
    # Path to where the actual gem binary is extracted:
    config.exe_path = "#{ENV['GEM_HOME']}/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-#{Gem.loaded_specs['wkhtmltopdf-binary'].version}/bin/wkhtmltopdf_debian_10_amd64"

    # Or a copied binary in the /bin/ path:
    config.exe_path = Rails.root.join('bin/wkhtmltopdf_debian_10_amd64').to_s
  end
end
```

Or, you could install the system's package for `wkhtmltopdf` (like apt-get install wkhtmltopdf), and point `exe_path` to there instead of using the gem.